# Foreach Query in 3 columns CSS

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hello I'd like to ask for help in regards to displaying the following query in 3 columns.
I think I need to read up on arrays, because I can't seem to get anything working..
Is it doable with this code of mine, or would I need to rewrite this before getting my desired result?

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) :?>
<?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_bryllup'))):$show = true;?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?>" value="<?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?>">
<h3><?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?></h3>
<p><?php echo $iyem->felt_beskrivelse; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
-Result1------Result2------Result3-
-Result4------Result5------Result6-
-etc-----------etc-----------etc---
```

Comment: It depends on what you wish to do exactly. Three columns could be easily achieved with three separate foreach loops styled in a three column setup with CSS. You would count the foreach loop in each column tp prevent multiple results.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you've added a diagram of what you like then it's even easier. You can do it with your existing loop

CSS

```
// set width to a third of the width of the containing div
div.result {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) :?>
<?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_bryllup'))):$show = true;?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?>" value="<?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?>">

<div class="result">
    <h3><?php echo $item->felt_titel; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $iyem->felt_beskrivelse; ?></p>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thought about doing it by css at first - dont know why I made it more complicated :-)